# VBA Excel count cells in a range with a specific value

Tags: excel, vba, counting

I am looking for a way to count the number of cells in a range with a specific value, but will skip cells that are next to the previous cell if they have the same value. So that if I have a series like 1,2,3,3,4,3 the result for the number of 3's would be 2.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I had `=COUNTIF([range],[criteria])-1` but if you have `1,2,3,4,3,4,3` you want to show `3` for the number of `3`s, correct?

Comment: Correct. I am trying to use visual basic specifically to count cells with a certain fill color. The number of cells with the color will almost never be the same. The formula I have now is For Each rcell In Range("B12:Z50") If rcell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) yellowcount = yellowcount + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,3)-COUNTIFS(A1:A1040000,3,A2:A1040001,3)
```

[image]

---

Edit:

The following formula works just as well:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A1040000,3,A2:A1040001,"<>" & 3)
```

In vba:

```
Dim output as Long
With AcitveSheet
    output = Application.WorksheetFunction.Countifs(.Range("A1:A1040000"),3,.Range(A2:A1040001),"<>" & 3)
End With
Debug.Print output
```

Comment: That is something I'll keep in mind when I don't need to use VBA, thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @Nachtstiel - If that works for you and answered your question, you can mark it as the "Answer" by clicking the check mark left of the post.

Comment: I found a solution for what i was looking for. I used
For Each rcell In Range("B12:Z50")
    If rcell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) And yellowprev = 0 Then
        yellowcount = yellowcount + 1
        yellowprev = yellowprev + 1
        If yellowprev > 5 Then
        yellowprev = 0
        End If
   ElseIf rcell.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
        yellowprev = 0
        End If